# Word for the kind of short sighing sound some audience members make during poetry readings?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

The sound I'm thinking of is really common at poetry readings. It's a kind of grunt (though grunt isn't right; it's softer, more like a sigh or a short moan) of recognition and approval, coming from the back of the throat with the mouth closed.

If you've not heard the sound at a public reading, it's sort of similar to the sound someone might make right after taking a bite of food they find extremely delicious.

I don't know if there's a word for this, but I'd be grateful for any ideas. Everything I've come up with doesn't seem to capture the essence of the sound at all.

Comment: umm.. or hmm... ? Or do you want a name for such class of sounds/words? Kindly provide an example sentence with a blank for this word.

Comment: @banuyayi - I’d go for “Mmmmm” instead.

Comment: Not sure about your noise. Merriam-Webster has [aah](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aah) "to exclaim in amazement, joy, or surprise".